# Create new variable where all values that are not between the 1st and the 99th percentile are substituted with missing values (NA)

Tags: r, if-statement, rank, dplyr

I want to copy the india04 dataframe and add a new variable called "incwage_adj" using mutate(), where all the income values between the 1st and the 99th percentile are substituted with missing values (NA).
Packages:

```
library(tidyverse)
require(nycflights13)
data(diamonds)
load("india04.Rdata")
```

Code:

```
india04_new <- india04 %>%
mutate(incwage_adj = ifelse(incwage != quantile(india04_new2$incwage, 0.99), NA, incwage))
```

Comment: YOu can use `ifelse(between(incwage, quantile(india04_new2$incwage, 0.99), incwage, NA)`

Comment: india04_new2 <- india04 %>%
    mutate(incwage_adj = ifelse(between(incwage, quantile(india04_new2$incwage, 0.99), incwage, NA)))                  Returns: "Error in between(incwage, quantile(india04_new2$incwage, 0.99), incwage, : unused argument (NA)"

Comment: I think your `quantile` needs to have two `probs` i.e. `ifelse(between(incwage, quantile(incwage, 0.01), quantile(incwage, 0.99)), incwage, NA))`

Comment: Now returns: Error in quantile.default(incwage, 0.01): missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

Comment: are you using `diamonds` or a different data

Comment: I am using different data

Comment: Basedon the error message, you can use `ifelse(between(incwage, quantile(incwage, 0.01, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(incwage, 0.99, na.rm = TRUE)), incwage, NA))`

Comment: A reproducible example `mtcars %>% mutate(mpg_adj =  ifelse(between(mpg, quantile(mpg, 0.01, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(mpg, 0.99, na.rm = TRUE)), mpg, NA))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
india04_new2$incwage[with(india04_new2, 
 incwage > quantile(incwage, 0.01) & incwage < quantile(incwage, 0.99))] <- NA
```

This should replace all the `incwage` which lie in between 1st and 99th percentile.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `between` to create a logical condition and change the values that are not between 1 and 99% to NA

```
library(dplyr)
 mtcars %>% 
    mutate(mpg_adj =  ifelse(between(mpg, 
      quantile(mpg, 0.01, na.rm = TRUE), 
      quantile(mpg, 0.99, na.rm = TRUE)), mpg, NA))
```

---

Or with `case_when`

```
mtcars %>% 
    mutate(mpg_adj =  case_when(between(mpg, 
      quantile(mpg, 0.01, na.rm = TRUE), 
      quantile(mpg, 0.99, na.rm = TRUE))~ mpg))
```